# Telerik RadGrid working examples

Tags: performance, telerik, radgrid

I'm looking for some examples of production websites that currently use the Telerik Rad Grid. I'd really like to see some real world scenarios in action, other than the Telerik RadGrid demo. Does anyone know of any websites that use it?

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://www.telerik.com/company/press-center/company-news/microsoft-implements-telerik-controls-in-msdn-technet-and-codeplex.aspx) from their website says that MSDN, TechNet, and CodePlex websites are using pieces of their components.

> "Microsoft has chosen to implement RadEditor in the Wiki Annotation Editor...[and] all Project Discussion pages, becoming the custom inline editor."

Answer (score 1):

Here is one for you...  The first tab uses the [RadGrid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx) control and the second tab uses the [RadScheduler](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/scheduler.aspx) control...

[link redacted per request of site owner]
`I will post blog on this later to demonstrate`

Answer (score 0):

There are some case studies on their website. like for [winforms](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/success-stories/case-studies.aspx), [asp.net ajax](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/success-stories.aspx) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Most controls like that are used in internal webapps. It is hard to provide public facing examples of sites using DataGrid-like at all(not impossible, just rare), let alone by one vendor on one platform.